# передать значение из js в value

Tags: jquery

```js
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0/?load=package.full&lang=ru-RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
                ymaps.ready(function(){
                    var geolocation = ymaps.geolocation;
                    $('#city').html('г. '+geolocation.city);
                }); 
            });
</script>
```

```html
<input type="text" id="city" name="city" value="1" class="form-control">
```

Как предать значение #city в value="1"

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так думаю

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
                ymaps.ready(async function(){
                    var geolocation = await ymaps.geolocation;
                    if (geolocation.city != undefined) {
                       $('#city').val('г. '+ geolocation.city);
                    } else {
                       $('#city').val('страна: '+ geolocation.country);
                    }
                }); 
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0/?load=package.full&lang=ru-RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
<input type="text" id="city" name="city" value="1" class="form-control">
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, теперь передает.

Comment: @Mr.Acula можете пометить ответ если помог, леве от ответа под стрелками